# How to restrict access to "Project Settings" in firebase console?

Tags: firebase

In my Firebase project's console, there are three users: two with admin roles and one as a developer. I want to limit the developer's access specifically to the "Project Settings" in the Firebase console, or at the very least, restrict their access to the "Users and Permissions" section.

What steps should I take to achieve this?

Comment: Everything related to access to a project in the Firebase console is documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview. I don't think there's any predefined role that just grants access to project settings, but you may be able to create a [custom role](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-custom) where you take away the user's permission to the specific products

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Thank you for the comment Frank. I tried creating a custom role but soon figured out it is a nightmare.